# cut point according specific interval

Tags: r, list, dplyr, intervals, cut

I have tried to summarize time gap between two variables and find length of the list.

My data set looks like this. I would like to get numbers of steps that their gaps are lower than 6:00.

```
Group   Time1   Gap
A   11:00:00 AM 
A   11:04:00 AM 4:00
A   11:06:00 AM 2:00
A   11:08:00 AM 2:00
A   11:12:00 AM 4:00
A   11:19:00 AM 7:00
A   11:26:00 AM 7:00
A   11:28:00 AM 2:00
A   11:30:00 AM 2:00
A   11:32:00 AM 2:00
A   11:34:00 AM 2:00
A   11:36:00 AM 2:00
```

End result should look like this;

```
Group   Gap   Step
    A   12:00  4
```

If interval is bigger than 6:00 I don't want to continue to count other steps.

I used filter option "... %>% filter(gap < 8:00)%>% ..." but it didn't work. I understand that cut point will split this list into two separate parts.

Sample DF:

```
    structure(list(Group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "A", class = "factor"), Time1 = structure(1:12, .Label = c("11:00:00 AM", 
"11:04:00 AM", "11:06:00 AM", "11:08:00 AM", "11:12:00 AM", "11:19:00 AM", 
"11:26:00 AM", "11:28:00 AM", "11:30:00 AM", "11:32:00 AM", "11:34:00 AM", 
"11:36:00 AM"), class = "factor"), Gap = structure(c(1L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("", "2:00", 
"4:00", "7:00"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Group", "Time1", 
"Gap"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Comment: I also need to find total time gap time in these 5 steps. In my example df, total time gap is equal the step 5th gap value!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way via `dplyr`,

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(Time1 = as.POSIXct(Time1, format = '%H:%M:%S'), step = row_number()-1) %>% 
  filter(Time1 - lag(Time1) > 6)

#  Group               Time1   Gap step
#1     A 2017-05-21 11:24:00 12:00    5
```

Comment: A `base R` option is `df <- transform(df, Time1 = as.POSIXct(Time1, format = '%H:%M:%S'), step = seq_len(nrow(df)));
subset(df, diff(Time1) > 6)`

Comment: Thanks for advice @Sotos. Actually, I used almost same script for my real data frame and it gave the wrong result. You can see my extended data frame and script in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43310503/dplyr-lag-and-difftime-give-wrong-results

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to create the "Step" column, which is just the row number minus one.

```
a %>% 
  mutate(Step=row_number()-1) %>%
```

Then, you need to extract the time from your given string, by removing the colon. Str_replace is from `library(stringr)`

```
mutate(gap = as.numeric(str_replace(Gap, ":", ""))) %>%
```

Filter, keeping only those where gap is greater than 600, which corresponds to a time greater than `"6:00"`.

```
filter(gap > 600) %>%
```

Then, keep only Group, Gap, and Step.

```
select(Group, Gap, Step)
```

Your final output:

```
    > df1 %>% 
+   mutate(Step=row_number()-1) %>%
+   mutate(gap=as.numeric(str_replace(Gap, ":", ""))) %>%
+   filter(gap > 600) %>%
+   select(Group, Gap, Step)

  Group   Gap Step
1     A 12:00    5
```

Comment: You could also define gap as a difftime object, `gap=as.difftime(as.character(Gap),format="%M:%S")`.

Comment: Thanks for  advice @ConCave. I tried to implement your method but I couldn't get it what I want. Could you check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43310503/dplyr-lag-and-difftime-give-wrong-results for expanded data frame and script.